# I cound'nt find buildscript in build.gradle(Project)

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

This is build.gradle(Project) what i knew.

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }


    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0'
    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

But my Project's build.gradle(Project) is that.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.1' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I tried to link Firebase with Android, but build.gradle(Project) was different from the file I knew.
I tried to modify it by force, but it didn't sync...
How can I access the Top-Level Gradle file??

Comment: So please post what error your facing ?

Comment: found solution?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

For Android Studio Bumblebee they are changed `build.gradle` structure.

You can add your `buildscript` above `plugins`

```
buildscript {
  dependencies {
    // Add our classpath 
     classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    // Add More 
 }
}
 plugins {
      id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.0' apply false
      id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.0' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
   delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: will writing buildscript{.. } allproject{...} still necessary in Bumblebee? The structures in settings.gradle is very similar.

Answer (score 0):

Try `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.1'` for Android Studio Bumblebee; Android Studio Arctic Fox still uses AGP up to `7.0.4`. In every case, you cannot add version `7.0.0` to class-path, but then use version `7.1.1`. These version numbers need to match. Most likely the Gradle wrapper also needs to be updated. Maybe think about version control once ...because one could basically sum up the question as "I've deleted a file, what now?"

Answer (score -3):

Please Check your Setting.gradle file.

Comment: Do I have to do what I did on "build.gradle" through "setting.gradle"?  It does look similar.

Comment: yess it would work same ad build.gradle file while writing code at setting.gradle

Comment: Okay i'll try, Thanks!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).