# Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.3.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

Tags: flutter, macos, gradle

This error appears when I try to run Gradle Run:

```
Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.3.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:8.3.0')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
    Google
    MavenRepo
```

My Build.Gradle Properties is the following:

```
 buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.3.0'
        // START: FlutterFire Configuration
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        // END: FlutterFire Configuration
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
plugins{
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.3.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.3.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.10' apply false
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'

subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.release('17.0.8.1')
}

org.gradle.java.home ='/usr/bin/java'
```

I've tried everything from putting the plugins commands outside buildscript and also using pluginManagement but nothing works

Answer (score 0):

Your build script is not valid,  `plugins {}` section should not be part of the top `buildscript {}` section.

You should probably have this structure :

```
buildscript {
    repositories  {
    }

    dependencies  {
         // ...
    }
}
plugins {
   // ...
}
```

see other related questions like [I cound'nt find buildscript in build.gradle(Project)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71063575/i-coundnt-find-buildscript-in-build-gradleproject)

and also check official documentation for real and clean working build setup : https://developer.android.com/build#groovy

Answer (score 0):

Your specified version of com.android.application plugin is invalid. The latest stable release is 8.2.0. Compare to https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.application/com.android.application.gradle.plugin

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio and Gradle versions matter, I have this issue often enough, and sometimes I forget what to do

Basically - did you try to sync with incompatible AS version? You can view/download latest versions [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview). Hedgehog is the current [stable release](https://developer.android.com/studio) and supports AGP (Android Gradle Plugin) 8.2, maybe you needed that?

Some other things to check:

- Check [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases#android_gradle_plugin_and_android_studio_compatibility) that your version of Android studio supports the AGP version
- Check [here](https://developer.android.com/build/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle) that your Gradle version (i.e., version in the gradle wrapper) and AGP are compatible
- [someone mentioned before] Check the released versions [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.application/com.android.application.gradle.plugin). Note the suffixes i.e., `-alphaXX`(etc)

Answer (score 0):

You should migrate from buildscript to plugins block:

migration guide from the old format of `buildscript` to `plugins` & `pluginManagement` : https://developer.android.com/build/migrate-to-kotlin-dsl#migrate-buildscript